# How to move subscription of a deleted Stripe plan to a new one which has same ID as deleted one?

Tags: stripe-payments

I had a Stripe plan `Basic` with an ID `basic_plan`. This plan had an annual subscription of $99. Users have used a coupon to get 100 discount of year 1. Recently I removed this plan and created a new plan called `Starter` with the same ID `basic_plan`. This plan is completely free now. But after the end of 1st year, my old users who were subscribed to `Basic` plan are being charged $99. Since the plan ID is same, how can I move my old users to new plan ?

Answer (score 0):

You have removed the old plan and recreated a new plan with the same name with different price.

Although the Plan's name are the same, however internal stripe treat the name as `Nickname` and the two plan are with totally different ID.

And your customer's plan is still pointing to the old plan ID with the same name.

You will need to remove the plan from the user and re add them to avoid the old charges.

in the future, if you want to update the pricing, try to `Update` the plan instead of `delete and create` a new plan.

Hope the above helps

Thanks